# All scripts have net::ERR_ABORTED 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm new in programming websites and stuff and I'm having trobules with those two codes:

```
function include_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '' , 1, true);

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');

}

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');



function loadjs()

    {
        wp_register_script ('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', '' , 1, true);
        wp_enqueue_script  ('customjs');



    }


    add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

Those two give me GET ... net::ERR_ABORTED 404 errors. Can't define JQuery other way, because it will give me mixed content errors. Help me guys!!

Comment: Mixed content warnings are usually to do with http / https aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
// remove the include_jquery function and combine below...


function loadjs() {

    // deregister WP loaded jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // register your custom jQuery
    wp_register_script('my-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '' , 1, true);

    // register your script and add 'my-jquery' as a deps
    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('my-jquery'), 1, true);

    // enqueue your js file will also load my-jquery since its a deps
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong with your code:

1. You need to remove the `add_action` from the `include_jquery()` function.
2. The files can't be found in your theme directory, hence the 404 error.
3. I would use `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead. `get_template_directory_uri()` uses the parent theme directory and not the child theme directory. You will also need a trailing slash added. Just make sure that the `js` folder exists in your theme.

Here is using your code:

```
function include_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '', 1, TRUE );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery' );

function loadjs() {
    wp_register_script( 'customjs', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/scripts.js', '', 1, TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs' );
```

You could also shorten this into a single function.

```
function include_js() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', '', 1, TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/scripts.js', '', 1, TRUE );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js' );
```